# Arduino Uno PWM, Transistors, hobby motors, external power supply 9v battery

Tags: arduino, voltage, transistors, pwm

If we use pulse width modulation to control transistor that connects to a motor should we take the voltage value as 9V or does it depend on the value in analogWrite().
Suppose if I write analogWrite(9, 200), which value should we use in calculations (9V/255)*200 = 7.06V or 9V?

Comment: This appears to be a arduino user-level question.  No electrical engineering in sight.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not know this site was only for electronics design questions.

Comment: It says *"Electrical Engineering"* right in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have connected your motor and transistor in the right way, that is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPtmQ5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

you will be changing the effective current and the effective voltage of your motor.  Now, what you do care about is **power**, the product of the two. This is how you know if your motor is running slower or faster, and the power is proportional to the PWM duty cycle. (Effective current and voltage are proportional to the square root of the duty cycle).

Let's say your motor drains 0.3 A in the constant current mode. The power it takes is 9V*0.3A = 2.7W. This is a power rating of your motor.

Writing analogWrite(9, 200) will make it give 200/255 * 2.7 = 2.1W.

EDIT: The transisotr will work as a switch in this way, what means it will flip between cut-off and saturation mode so Vce will be 0V when it's conducting.

Comment: Not true, even when in saturation mode there is a voltage drop across the transistor. Look up any transistor datasheet for \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$

Comment: Connection is exactly the same way as in your diagram. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you used 9V as your answer then regardless of what your PWM was you would always have the same answer which is incorrect, the instantaneously measured voltage would be 9V but you're not after the instantaneous voltage.

If you want the exact value then your calculation will be something like \$V = ((V_{BATT}-V_{CE})/255)\times 200\$.

\$V_{CE}\$ can be found in the datasheet of your transistor. Substitute the 200 for whatever PWM value you are using. The reason I specify \$V_{BATT}\$ as opposed to 9V is that the voltage will fall over time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the formula for the calculation.